# Add image to centered heading without shifting text alignment

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add an image to a centered h1 element without the text alignment changing at all?

In other words, the image would not be centered, but to the left of the text with spacing of 20px between the image and the text. It would not be all the way on the left of the page. The text would be centered in the same place regardless of the size of the image.

My code currently moves the text to adjust for the image and is as follows:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
   <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="50px" height="auto">Centered Text
</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to add a `<span>` around your text, you could then use absolute position to place the image (you'd have to use calc() to align it right: 100% + your 20 px offset from the edge of the span):

```css
h1 span {
  position: relative;
}
h1 span img {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 20px);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
  <span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="logo" width="50px" height="auto">Centered Text</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes with CSS-Grid

```css
h1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

h1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 200%;
  width: 1px;
  background: red;
}

img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300" alt="logo" width="50px" height="auto">Centered Text
</h1>

<h1>
  <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300" alt="logo" width="100px" height="auto">Centered Text
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block-panel{
}

.block-panel .img-block{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.block-panel .text-block{
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-panel">
  <div class="img-block"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></div>
  <div class="text-block">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="logo" width="50px" height="auto" style="
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: initial;
    display: inherit;">Centered Text
</h1>
```